# Reindexing Search by Store Id

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, indexing

I noticed something when looking over the source code and noticed that the catalog search indexer can fire for a specific store by accepting a $storeId parameter.
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php

```
  /**
     * Regenerate search index for specific store
     *
     * @param int $storeId Store View Id
     * @param int|array $productIds Product Entity Id
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext
     */
    protected function _rebuildStoreIndex($storeId, $productIds = null)
```

Has anyone needed to specifically target the search indexer for a specific store? If so it doesn't look like Magento provides a decent way of calling this method as the rebuildIndex function itself just loops through the stores and calls it.

```
public function rebuildIndex($storeId = null, $productIds = null)
{
    if (is_null($storeId)) {
        $storeIds = array_keys(Mage::app()->getStores());
        foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
            $this->_rebuildStoreIndex($storeId, $productIds);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_rebuildStoreIndex($storeId, $productIds);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Might be a neat n98-magerun feature. 
n98-magerun.phar index:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext $store_id

Comment: Actually rebuildIndex only loops through stores if $storeId is not provided. So you can call public rebuildIndex for specific store.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton said, you can just provide a store_id to the function. This works, I haven't felt the need myself yet as we tend to switch to Solr for bigger environments.